# Jquery JSON and C# : Reading JSON reply from C# HttpHandler

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am having some trouble figuring out to read the JSON returned from my HttpHandler.

The data being returned is this (according to Firebug):

```
[{"ID":2,"Name":"Fred Johnson","PhoneNumber":"444-444-4444","Notes":"Note Data","Representative":1,"StreetNumber":76547,"StreetName":"Juniper St.","City":"Burbank"}]
```

### HttpHandler Code

```
public class RequestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public RequestHandler()
    { }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var thisID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["Id"]);
        List<WW.Data.Customer> thisCustomer = WW.Business.Customer.getCustomerByID(thisID);
        JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string lookedUpCustomer = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(thisCustomer);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.Write(lookedUpCustomer);
    }
}
```

### JQUERY CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendData() {
        alert("start");
        var thisID = $("#Text1").val()
        var arr = { ID: thisID};
        $.ajax(
           {
               url: "jsonpost.ww",
               type: "POST",
               data: arr,
               dataType: 'json',
               async: true,
               success: function (data) {
                   $("#Text2").val = data.Name;
                   $("#Text3").val = data.StreetNumber;
                   $("#Text4").val = data.StreetName;
                   $("#Text5").val = data.City;
                   $("#Text6").val = data.PhoneNumber;
               }
           }
        );
        alert("end");
    }
</script>
```

So basically, I am having trouble reading that JSON string data when it is returned on success.  Anyone see anything that would cause this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
CSS

Comment: How does one award both answers?  They both were correct in fixing my problem(s)?

Comment: I am thinking about awarding the answer to the first responder. Thoughts?

Comment: both thumbs are up from myside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `json` response which you are getting should be in `()`:

```
     $("#Text2").val(data.Name);
     $("#Text3").val(data.StreetNumber);
     $("#Text4").val(data.StreetName);
     $("#Text5").val(data.City);
     $("#Text6").val(data.PhoneNumber);
```

This is the correct way of assigning values to `inputs`.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is formatted such that the object you need is the first element of an array. So in your success callback, instead of doing `data.name`, you need to do `data[0].name`.

Comment: Just know that your answer was helpful as well but I had to give it to the guy who answered first.  I appreciate your guidance and effort,

Comment: Glad to have helped. Btw, I did answer before the other guy by 1min :).

Comment: @CSSHell Also the other answer doesn't mention anything about the result being an array (`data[0].name`).