# Creating Javascript object using loop with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, flot

I have a sql table which looks like this :

```
+------+------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| SrNo | BidderName | BidAmt  |       BidDate       | BidTicks  |
+------+------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
|    1 | ARBAAZ     | 500.00  | Apr 30 2015 10:27AM | 348854000 |
|    2 | SHEKHAR    | 600.00  | Apr 30 2015 10:28AM | 348845000 |
|    3 | SHEKHAR    | 800.00  | Apr 30 2015 10:28AM | 348838000 |
+------+------------+---------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I am sending this to my clientside in JSON format.

I am able to fetch values in following manner:

```
var data;

Table.forEach(function (field) {
    var name = field.BidderName;
    var amount = field.BidAmt;
    data = "";
});
```

I am trying to create a object which looks like this from `Table` for my flot graph:

```
var dataset = [
    {
        label: "ARBAAZ",
        data: [[348854000, 500.00]],//created from [bidticks,bidamt]
        color: "#FF0000",
        points: { fillColor: "#FF0000", show: true },
        lines: { show: true }
    },
    {
        label: "SHEKHAR",
        data: [[348845000, 600.00], [48838000, 800.00]],
        color: "#0062E3",
        points: { fillColor: "#0062E3", show: true },
        lines: { show: true }
    }
];
```

Any ideas, how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can visit these links [Link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203621/Call-HTTPhandler-from-jQuery-Pass-data-and-retriev) [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199443/jquery-json-and-c-sharp-reading-json-reply-from-c-sharp-httphandler)

Comment: describe the structure of your final report...

Comment: It seems to me like you need to pivot the results. To-do so, get a list of distinct bidder names, then iterate though the distinct list, and where the name matches the names in the original data-set select the value into data.

Comment: Or the better solution is...don't do it on client-side...

Comment: @deostroll this is the final structure. I mean Flot graph needs a `dataset` variable passed to it which needs to be in this format. I have shown the backend table. I just somehow have to convert it into the desired format of `dataset`

Comment: @deostroll I was thinking the same thing. I think it would be easier on the serverside. But not quite able to wrap my head around it yet.

Comment: @Arbaaz Where is data like `Team red` or `Team blue` in the data...? Or numbers like `1430369878000`, `1430369879000`, etc...for that matter...

Comment: Do you use backbone.js ? It will be pretty straightforward then.

Comment: BidTicks is the number. (i know the data does not match in the example) 
Team red and Team blue should be Arbaaz, Shekhar in the example. I will edit it . btw for color i might include it in the database table or spefify a random color.

Comment: @user3048967 I dont, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your json data is in var 'data',
you can loop through with `filter` function,

```
  var seen = {};
    data = data.filter(function(entry) {
        var previous;

        // Have we seen this label before?
        if (seen.hasOwnProperty(entry.label)) {
            // Yes, grab it and add this data to it
            previous = seen[entry.label];
            var data = [entry.BidTicks, entry.BidAmt] ;
            previous.data.push(data);

            // Don't keep this entry, we've merged it into the previous one
            return false;
        }    

        // entry.data probably isn't an array; make it one for consistency

        entry.data = [];
        var data = [entry.BidTicks, entry.BidAmt] ;
        entry.data.push(data);

        //delete the attributes which are not required in final output
        delete entry.BidTicks;
        delete entry.BidAmt;

        // Remember that we've seen it
        seen[entry.label] = entry;

        // Keep this one, we'll merge any others that match into it
        return true;
    });
```

Working fiddle is here--> [fiddle to filter the array of objects](https://jsfiddle.net/1edjv9zr/2/)

About your extra attributes 'color', 'lines' etc,  I'm sure  you can bring those into final output now.

Comment: how do i break it into chunks for different bidders? As you can see the dataset has 2 chunks  in the example, one each for Arbaaz and Shekhar

Comment: @Arbaaz I  edited the answer to reflect the exact change you need. Please accept the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exact data structure you are having in json object. 
But, I think you can do like this

```
   $.each(data, function(index, statistic) {
        if (statistic.BidderName == 'Team Red') {
            teamRed.push([statistic.BidAmt, statistic.timeStamp]);
        } else {
            teamBlue.push([statistic.BidAmt, statistic.timeStamp]);
        }
    });
```

Now you can use teamRed and teamBlue in **dataset** object.

I am assuming you do have this BidderName which will differentiate either this row belong to blue or red team.

Comment: Team Read is actually Arbaaz and Shekhar from Table. I should have corrected the example.

Comment: I am sorry I should have corrected the example. The team red and blue arenothing but the names returned from Table. Arbaaz and Shekhar. I have updated the question. All I have is dataset structure.